# Getting JBoss AOP working on my code

Tags: java, jboss, aop

I've defined an Aspect class, annotated at class level and again at the method level with a pointcut to hit all public method executions. The method just fires off a log statement and does the standard invocation call. This is wrapped up in a jar renamed as aop, with a META-INF/jboss-aop.xml and dumped in the jboss deploy directory, alongside the application ear.

I've got load time weaving set to true in the jboss aop deployer's mbean xml.

My method is called on some org.jboss.jms methods when the server starts, but I don't see it fired for anything else.

Is there something I need to do to enable it to work with my application/packages?

JBoss 4.2.3.
Java 5, not using -javaagent.
Apologies; I can't post code samples, the code is on a network with no internet or external media access, so this is all from memory.

Comment: If you are using Java 1.5+ and loadtime weaving, the best way to do this is to use the javaagent option. Any reason why you're not using it ?

Comment: Just didn't manage to configure it, it seemed optional. Should that affect it being selective as to which packages it works on?

Comment: I've had it working (albeit with an interceptor instead of an aspect) now, at home, but it doesn't work at work still - same symptom of it logging org.jboss.jms methods but nothing in any other package, including the ones with my code in.